# Flutter function inside a loop from specific index

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to run a function depending if the data contains certain requirements, within a loop of data being displayed fetched from the database.

```dart
for (var i = 0; i < int.parse(_resultLength); i++)
  Container(
    width: size.width,
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
      top: 8,
    ),
    child: _usersPosts[i].postImg == "false"
        ? Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
              left: 5,
              right: 5,
            ),
            child: Text(
              _usersPosts[i].postText,
              textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
          )
        : Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 5,
                  right: 5,
                ),
                child: Text(
                  _usersPosts[i].postText,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              _postWithImageFunction(_usersPosts[i].postId),
            ],
          ),
  ),
```

So basically if this requirement is not met `_usersPosts[i].postImg == "false"`, then I want to run a function to fetch more data from the database which is this `_postWithImageFunction(_usersPosts[i].postId)`, which I am sending with it the current post ID, or to better understand the current index from the loop being displayed.

```dart
_postWithImageFunction(String postId) {
  List imgList = [];

  _getPostImages(postId);
  // _getPostImagesStored(postId);
  if (_resultLengthImage == '0') {
    return _postWithImage(postId, imgList, false);
  } else if (_resultLengthImage != '0') {
    int count = _userPostImages[0].count;
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
      imgList.add(_userPostImages[i].postImg);
    }
    return Text(imgList.toString());
    // return _postWithImage(postId, imgList, true);
  }
}
```

This is the function code, I know this may not be the most optimal code, but this is just to test it out and see if there are some outcomes. This code actually fetches the data, but since there's more than one post ID's that has to go fetch more data, it seems that it it rerunning the function for all the posts that needs to run the function and changing the data for all of them instead of just that ONE post or index, so basically lets say the outcome shows the postID 59 and keeps changing to postID 61 but changes it to all of the posts instead of that specific one. I don't know if I am explaining this clearly, if not please message me in comments and I am sorry about it. If you do please help me out, because I am definitely doing something wrong and need some help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You checked your postImg for "false" which is basically a string and not the boolean false. Thus your code never  satisfies the true condition and changes all the data.

You did this:

> `_usersPosts[i].postImg == "false"`

You need to change it to this:

> `_usersPosts[i].postImg == false`

or you could do this (much less error prone):

> `!_usersPosts[i].postImg`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the only problem though is that the data of true or false comes from the database itself, and I can't figure out a way to catch the data as bool, thats why Im catching it as String and have to use "false" in ". I don't know if you know a way. Thanks again, appreciate your answer

Comment: Although now that I think of it, I don’t really think this is the main problem, cause this part of the condition is not a problem at all, it is “detecting” when the requirement has met and does proceed as I want to, the problem is when the function runs, instead of running on its own postID, it runs all the posts that does meet the requirements, lets say 3 of the posts out of 61 posts, but it runs all 3 of those posts instead of 1 for each post, idk if u understand what Im referring to… lool